# Найденные файлы копируются в одну папку и заменяются сами собой

Tags: python, файлы, файловая-система, txt, scripts

В предыдущем вопросе у меня все получилось сделать, но столкнулся с одной проблемой. Мне нужно, чтобы все файлы которые мой скрипт нашел - копировались в одну папку, но названия всех нужных мне txt - одинаковые, просто они в разных папках. И разумеется, при переносе в одну - они заменяют сами себя, что в конечном итоге оставляет мне 1 файл место 100 (образно).
Есть ли вариант при переносе файлов изменять их имена?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пример - как вы хотите чтобы назывались ваши файлы: исходное название и то название, которое нужно дать файлу с учётом счётчика предложенного MaxU. Ну или предложите ваш вариант, как вы хотите чтобы у вас сохранялось много файлов с одним именем. В принципе, можно и GUID к названию файла приписывать, но будет громоздко выглядеть.

Comment: Мне без разницы как они будут называться, хоть 1.txt 2.txt и т.д. Мне лишь бы они просто не сталкивались друг с другом, перезаменяя себя.

Answer (score 2):

Заведите словарь, где ключем будет имя файла, а значением - счетчик (сколько раз этот файл уже встречался) и переименовывайте файл, добавляя значение счетчика.

Comment: Можно не много подробней ? Я не профессионал в пайтоне, а новичек с совсем малым опытом и даже гугля - многое не понимаю

Comment: @eviable, CrazyElf уже все реализовал )

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам пример:

```
from os import path
from collections import defaultdict

files = ['/usr/data/file1.txt', '/usr/data/file2.txt', '/usr/data/file1.txt', '/usr/data/file1.txt', '/usr/data/file2.txt', '/usr/data/file3.txt']

d = defaultdict(int)
for file in files:
    d[file] += 1
    s = path.splitext(file)
    file = f'{s[0]}_{d[file]}{s[1]}'
    print(file)
```

На выходе:

```
/usr/data/file1_1.txt
/usr/data/file2_1.txt
/usr/data/file1_2.txt
/usr/data/file1_3.txt
/usr/data/file2_2.txt
/usr/data/file3_1.txt
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку, что path.splitext(file) is not defined

Comment: `from os import path` не забыли сделать?

Comment: нет, не забыл, код идентично вашему, только поменял пути на свои

Comment: Покажите полный текст ошибки, как есть, не в пересказе. В Google Colab этот код работает без ошибок

Comment: Извиняюсь что так долго не было, занят был. Ту проблему я решил, но теперь появилась другая. Скрипт действительно меняет название файла, но как только он начинает считывать новый путь - он запускается заново, и соответственно отчет тоже. А следовательно - ко второму файлу также добавляется 1, место 2.
Изменил свой вопрос выше и добавил пикчу с проблемой

Comment: @eviable Не совсем понятно всё-таки - как вы собираете и обрабатываете список файлов. По словарю нужно проверять не *входные* имена файлов, а *выходные*, в которые вы собираетесь файлы записывать. Но если вы делаете копирование всех файлов не за один проход, тогда этот метод не поможет, нужно тогда совсем по-другому делать. Покажите, как вы встроили мой код в свой код, иначе непонятно, что подсказывать.

Comment: Я нашел в чем корень проблемы. Она состоит в том, что ваш код работает при условии, что пути к файлам одинаковые, т.е. они должны лежать в одной папке. Но ваш код не работает, при условии, когда пути к файлам разные, а названия одинаковые, тогда когда мне надо, чтобы это работало даже при разных путях.

С таким кодом, он новые пути считает как новое значение,  и заново начинает дописывать ему единицу, вместо того чтобы продолжить цикл добавления цифр, как надо.

Comment: @eviable Так вы не в один каталог файлы складываете, а в разные, но при этом нужно, чтобы названия всё-равно инкрементировались? Приведите больше примеров в вопросе. А вообще отделить название от каталога не сложно, в том же `path` есть много разных методов.

Comment: Напишу блок схему, чтобы было легче.
1. Получить путь в переменную X и получить путь куда сохраняем Y.
2. Сделать уникальный путь в Y.
3. Скопировать файл по пути X в путь Y + переименовать сразу т.е. мы копируем из X в путь Y с новым названием уже.